# Unix Shell: Summing up values, one per line but skipping every nth row

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to design a Unix shell script (preferably generic sh) that will take a file whose contents are numbers, one per line. These numbers are the CPU idle time from mpstat obtained by:

```
cat ${PARSE_FILE} | awk '{print $13}' | grep "^[!0-9]" > temp.txt
```

So the file is a list if numbers, like:

```
46.19
93.41
73.60
99.40
95.80
96.00
77.10
99.20
52.76
81.18
69.38
89.80
97.00
97.40
76.18
97.10
```

What these values really are is that line 1 is for Core 1, line 2 for Core 2, etc... for X number of cores (in my case 8) - so every 9th line is again for Core 1, etc...

The original file looks something like this:

```
10/28/2013  Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 (host)  10/28/2013  _x86_64_    

(32 CPU)
10/28/2013  
10/28/2013  02:25:05 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    0   51.20    0.00    2.61    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   46.19
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    1    6.09    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   93.41
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    2   25.20    0.00    1.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   73.60
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    3    0.40    0.00    0.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.40
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    4    3.80    0.00    0.40    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.80
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    5    3.70    0.00    0.30    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.00
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    6   21.70    0.00    1.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   77.10
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    7    0.70    0.00    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.20
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    0   45.03    0.00    1.61    0.00    0.00    0.60    0.00    0.00   52.76
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    1   17.82    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   81.18
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    2   29.62    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   69.38
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    3    9.70    0.00    0.40    0.00    0.00    0.10    0.00    0.00   89.80
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    4    2.40    0.00    0.60    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.00
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    5    2.00    0.00    0.60    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.40
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    6   22.92    0.00    0.90    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   76.18
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    7    2.40    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.10
```

I'm trying to design a script that will take the number of cores and this file as a variable and get me the average for each core and I'm not sure how to do this. Here is what I have:

```
cat ${PARSE_FILE} | awk '{print $13}' | grep "^[!0-9]" > temp.txt
NUMBER_OF_CORES=8
NUMBER_OF_LINES=`awk ' END { print NR } ' temp.txt`
NUMBER_OF_VALUES=`echo "scale=0;${NUMBER_OF_LINES}/${NUMBER_OF_CORES}" | bc`
for i in `seq 1 ${NUMBER_OF_CORES}`
do
  awk 'NR % $i == 0' temp.txt
  echo Core: ${i} Average: xx
done
```

So I have the number of values (lines over cores) that each core has, so that is every nth line I need to skip but I'm not sure how to cleanly do this. I basically need to loop every "NUMBER_OF_CORES" times through the file, skipping every "NUMBER_OF_CORES" line and summing them up to divide by "NUMBER_OF_VALUES".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do ?

```
awk '/CPU/&&/idle/{f=1;next}f{a[$4]+=$13;b[$4]++}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]/b[i]}}' your_file
```

Actually the number of cores is not needed here. It will calculate average idle time for all the cores available in the file

Tested:

```
> cat temp
10/28/2013  Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 (host)  10/28/2013  _x86_64_    

(32 CPU)
10/28/2013  
10/28/2013  02:25:05 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    0   51.20    0.00    2.61    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   46.19
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    1    6.09    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   93.41
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    2   25.20    0.00    1.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   73.60
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    3    0.40    0.00    0.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.40
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    4    3.80    0.00    0.40    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.80
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    5    3.70    0.00    0.30    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.00
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    6   21.70    0.00    1.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   77.10
10/28/2013  02:25:15 PM    7    0.70    0.00    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.20
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    0   45.03    0.00    1.61    0.00    0.00    0.60    0.00    0.00   52.76
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    1   17.82    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   81.18
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    2   29.62    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   69.38
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    3    9.70    0.00    0.40    0.00    0.00    0.10    0.00    0.00   89.80
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    4    2.40    0.00    0.60    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.00
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    5    2.00    0.00    0.60    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.40
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    6   22.92    0.00    0.90    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   76.18
10/28/2013  02:25:25 PM    7    2.40    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.10
> nawk '/CPU/&&/idle/{f=1;next}f{a[$4]+=$13;b[$4]++}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]/b[i]}}' temp
2 71.49
3 94.6
4 96.4
5 96.7
6 76.64
7 98.15
0 49.475
1 87.295
>
```

Comment: There's a lot of good answers here but for my needs, this works the best. It's simple and direct. Adding a "| sort -n" to the end puts this in order of CPU number.

Answer (score 1):

The script below countCores.sh is based on the data you gave in temp.txt
This may not be what you want but will give you some ideas. I was'nt sure
what overall total average you wanted so I just chose to show average of the values
in column one for all 8 cores.  I also used cat -n to represent the core number.
Hope This helps.  VonBell

```
#!/bin/bash
#Execute As: countCores.sh temp.txt 8
AllCoreTotals=0
DataFile="$1"
NumCores="$2"
AllCoreTotals=0
NumLines="`cat -n $DataFile|cut -f1|tail -1|tr -d " "`"
PrtCols="`echo $NumLines / $NumCores|bc`"
clear;echo;echo
echo "============================================================="
pr -t${PrtCols} $DataFile|tr -d "\t"|tr -s " "  "+"|bc |\
while read CoreTotal
    do
       CoreAverage=`echo $CoreTotal / $PrtCols|bc`
       echo "$CoreTotal     Core Average $CoreAverage"
       AllCoreTotals="`echo $CoreTotal + $AllCoreTotals|bc`"
       echo "$AllCoreTotals"  > AllCoreTot.tmp
    done|cat -n
AllCoreAverage=`cat AllCoreTot.tmp`
AllCoreAverage="`echo $AllCoreAverage / $NumCores|bc`"
echo "============================================================="
echo "(Col One) Total Core Average: $AllCoreAverage "
rm $DataFile
rm AllCoreTot.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it for all cores at the same time:

```
awk -f prog.awk ${PARSE_FILE}
```

Then in `prog.awk` put

```
    {   if ((NF == 13) && ($4 != "CPU"))
        {   SUM[$4] += $13;
            CNT[$4]++;
        }
    }
END {   for(loop in SUM)
        {   printf("CPU: %d  Total: %d  Count: %d  Average: %d\n",
                    loop, SUM[loop], CNT[loop], SUM[loop]/CNT[loop]);
        }
    }
```

If you want to do it on one line:

```
awk '{if ((NF == 13) && ($4 != "CPU")){SUM[$4] += $13;CNT[$4]++;}} END {for(loop in SUM){printf("CPU: %d  Total: %d  Count: %d  Average: %d\n", loop, SUM[loop], CNT[loop], SUM[loop]/CNT[loop]);}}'  ${PARSE_FILE}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more study, this snippet seems to do the trick:

```
#Parse logs to get CPU averages for cores
PARSE_FILE=`ls ~/logs/*mpstat*`
echo "Parsing ${PARSE_FILE}..."
cat ${PARSE_FILE} | awk '{print $13}' | grep "^[!0-9]" > temp.txt
NUMBER_OF_CORES=8
NUMBER_OF_LINES=`awk ' END { print NR } ' temp.txt`
NUMBER_OF_VALUES=`echo "scale=0;${NUMBER_OF_LINES}/${NUMBER_OF_CORES}" | bc`
TOTAL=0
for i in `seq 1 ${NUMBER_OF_CORES}`
do
  sed -n $i'~'$NUMBER_OF_CORES'p' temp.txt > temp2.txt
  SUM=`awk '{s+=$0} END {print s}' temp2.txt`
  AVERAGE=`echo "scale=0;${SUM}/${NUMBER_OF_VALUES}" | bc`
  echo Core: ${i} Average: `expr 100 - ${AVERAGE}`
  TOTAL=$((TOTAL+${AVERAGE}))
done
TOTAL_AVERAGE=`echo "scale=0;${TOTAL}/${NUMBER_OF_CORES}" | bc`
echo "Total Average: `expr 100 - ${TOTAL_AVERAGE}`"
rm temp*.txt
```